# Error de ejecución programa VB en C# conectando con MySql

Tags: c#, windows-forms, vba

Tengo un error cuando ejecuto el programa:

---

Error code:

> The thread 0x2da0 has exited with code 0 (0x0). Exception thrown:
>   'System.NullReferenceException' in Dapper.dll Error: Exception
>   Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
>   Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in
>   MySql.Data.dll Warning:Exception Column count doesn't match value
>   count at row 1 The program '[26420] UsuarisWindowsFormsApp.exe' has

---

Código:

namespace UsuarisWindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

```
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private const string connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=biblioteca;Uid=usuari;Pwd=seCret_16";

    private void registerButton_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PasswordTextBox.Text == ConfirmPasswordTextBox.Text) 
        { 
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            string sql = "SELECT MAX(ID_USR) FROM USUARIS";
            int newId = 0;
            try {
                newId = cnn.Query<int>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Exception " + ex.Message);
            }

            //corregir linia insert into
            // string sqlInsert = $"INSERT ID_USR, DNI_USR, LLINATGE1, POB_USR, EMAIL_USR, PASSWORD INTO USUARIS VALUES " +
                //$"({newId + 1}, '{NIFTextBox.Text}', '{NameTextBox.Text}','{SurnameTextBox.Text}','{TownComboBox.Text}','{EmailTextBox.Text}','{PasswordTextBox.Text}')";
            string sqlInsert = $"INSERT INTO usuaris (ID_USR, DNI_USR, LLINATGE1, POB_USR, EMAIL_USR, PASSWORD) VALUES " +
                $"({newId + 1}, '{NIFTextBox.Text}', '{NameTextBox.Text}','{SurnameTextBox.Text}','{TownComboBox.Text}','{EmailTextBox.Text}','{PasswordTextBox.Text}')";
            try
            {
                var rowsAffected = cnn.Execute(sqlInsert);
                if (rowsAffected == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("User Register Correctly. ", "User Manager", MessageBoxButtons.OK );
                    NIFTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                    NameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                    SurnameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                    TownComboBox.Text = string.Empty;
                    EmailTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                    PasswordTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            } catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Warning:Exception " + ex.Message);
            }


            cnn.Close();
        }
    }

    private void PasswordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value {NameTextBox.Text} doesn't have a column assigned.
The correct code:

(El value {NameTextBox.Text} no tiene una columna asignada.
El código correcto es:)

```
private const string connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=biblioteca;Uid=usuari;Pwd=seCret_16";

private void registerButton_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PasswordTextBox.Text == ConfirmPasswordTextBox.Text) 
    { 
        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "SELECT MAX(ID_USR) FROM USUARIS";
        int newId = 0;
        try {
            newId = cnn.Query<int>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Exception " + ex.Message);
        }

        //corregir linia insert into
        // string sqlInsert = $"INSERT ID_USR, DNI_USR, NOM_USR, LLINATGE1, POB_USR, EMAIL_USR, PASSWORD INTO USUARIS VALUES " +
            //$"({newId + 1}, '{NIFTextBox.Text}', '{NameTextBox.Text}','{SurnameTextBox.Text}','{TownComboBox.Text}','{EmailTextBox.Text}','{PasswordTextBox.Text}')";
        string sqlInsert = $"INSERT INTO usuaris (ID_USR, DNI_USR, LLINATGE1, POB_USR, EMAIL_USR, PASSWORD) VALUES " +
            $"({newId + 1}, '{NIFTextBox.Text}', '{NameTextBox.Text}','{SurnameTextBox.Text}','{TownComboBox.Text}','{EmailTextBox.Text}','{PasswordTextBox.Text}')";
        try
        {
            var rowsAffected = cnn.Execute(sqlInsert);
            if (rowsAffected == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User Register Correctly. ", "User Manager", MessageBoxButtons.OK );
                NIFTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                NameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                SurnameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                TownComboBox.Text = string.Empty;
                EmailTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                PasswordTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        } catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Warning:Exception " + ex.Message);
        }


        cnn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: por favor coloca tu respuesta en español. Recuerda que esto es StackOverflow en español!.